# Cilium pods crashing due to invalid range ip of node

Tags: kubernetes, cilium

I am deploying a **kubernetes** cluster using **kubespray**.
I changed the network pluggin from calico to **cilium**.

Unfortunatly some of the cilium pods are stuck in CrashLoopBackOff.

```
kubectl --namespace kube-system get pods --selector k8s-app=cilium --sort-by='.status.containerStatuses[0].restartCount' -o wide
NAME           READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE          NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
cilium-2gmwm   1/1     Running            0          14m   10.10.3.102   nodemaster1   <none>           <none>
cilium-9ccdp   1/1     Running            0          14m   10.10.3.110   node6         <none>           <none>
cilium-c9nh6   1/1     Running            0          14m   10.10.3.107   node3         <none>           <none>
cilium-r9w4z   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   6          14m   10.10.3.109   node5         <none>           <none>
cilium-f8z2q   1/1     Running            0          14m   10.10.3.105   node1         <none>           <none>
cilium-d96cd   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   7          14m   10.10.3.106   node2         <none>           <none>
cilium-jgmcf   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   7          14m   10.10.3.103   nodemaster2   <none>           <none>
cilium-9zqnr   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   7          14m   10.10.3.108   node4         <none>           <none>
cilium-llt9p   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   7          14m   10.10.3.104   nodemaster3   <none>           <none>
```

When checking the logs of the crashed pods I can see this fatal error message :

```
level=fatal msg="The allocation CIDR is different from the previous cilium instance. This error is most likely caused by a temporary network disruption to the kube-apiserver that prevent Cilium from retrieve the node's IPv4/IPv6 allocation range. If you believe the allocation range is supposed to be different you need to clean up all Cilium state with the `cilium cleanup` command on this node. Be aware this will cause network disruption for all existing containers managed by Cilium running on this node and you will have to restart them." error="Unable to allocate internal IPv4 node IP 10.233.71.1: provided IP is not in the valid range. The range of valid IPs is 10.233.70.0/24." subsys=daemon
```

It seems that the node's IP (**10.233.71.1** in this case)  is not respecting the valid range of **10.233.70.0/24**.

I tried to modify the main.yaml file of kubespray to change the subnet but my multiple attempts only made the number of crash go up and down...

For instance this run I tried with :

```
kube_service_addresses: 10.233.0.0/17
kube_pods_subnet: 10.233.128.0/17
kube_network_node_prefix: 18
```

As you can see it did not work.
If you have any idears... :-)
Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed the problem with the help of the Cilium devs !

You have to set the key `clean-cilium-state` from **false** to **true** in the kubespray file `kubespray/roles/network_plugin/cilium/templates/cilium-config.yml.j2`

After the deployment you have to revert this boolean. To do so, execute `kubectl edit configmap cilium-config -n kube-system` and change back the key `clean-cilium-state` from **true** to **false**.

Finally you have to kill the cilium pods.
List the pods : `kubectl get pods -n kube-system`
Kill the pods : `kubectl delete pods cilium-xxx cilium-xxx ...`

This is now listed as an [issue](https://github.com/cilium/cilium/issues/6469) on the Cilium repo